# Send a variable to form parameter in request HTTP POST node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

I'm trying to send an HTTP POST request through Node js.

Here's my code:

```
var tentativa = "{ id:'" +  result.rows[i][0] + "', timestamp:'" + result.rows[i][1]+"', application: '"+ applicationName +
              "', type:'Log', source: '" + result.rows[i][2] + "', " + string+ " }";

            request({
              uri: "http://localhost:5000/logs",
              method: "POST",
              form:   tentativa,
              headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
              }, function(error, response, body) {
                console.log(body);

            });
```

When I send the "tentativa" variable in the form, the request its sent but not saves anything. But when I send the output of the "tentativa" variable it work fine. Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: the `form` property should probably just be a regular JavaScript object, rather than a string representation of the object. The `request` library will convert it for you and properly encode it into the HTTP request.

Comment: "...request throw Node.js" do you mean node.js is throwing an error? What's the error?

Comment: @borislemke it isn't throw is through. sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0):

this is not a valid json

```
var tentativa = "{ id:'" +  result.rows[i][0] + "', timestamp:'" + result.rows[i][1]+"', application: '"+ applicationName +
              "', type:'Log', source: '" + result.rows[i][2] + "', " + string+ " }";
```

the last value miss the key property, this is probably why it's not sending the object along with the request.

And since it looks you want to send a plain json, you can just put the object inside the body.

```
request({
     uri: "http://localhost:5000/logs",
     method: "POST",
     body:   tentativa,
     json: true,
     headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"}
  }

  }, function(error, response, body) {
      console.log(body);

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the help.
Solved the problem using a javascript object instead of that string, like @varbrad said.